# Incorrect field name resulted in RuntimeError: ERROR 999999 (Also, better code for adding and calculating fields)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, field-calculator, cursor

This is the bottom half of my code (and it's been edited somewhat to share publicly). The code works perfectly fine when the `fieldList` has only three fields in it, but when I populate it with all 108 fields, I receive the following error, just before it starts to calculate fields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GIS\1GIS_DATA\Folder1\Folder2\Python and Tools\RunThisPythonCode.py", line 125, in <module>
    value = row.getValue(field)* row.anotherField #<--This is the line the error is referring to
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.0\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py", line 944, in getValue
    return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(self._arc_object.GetValue(*gp_fixargs(args)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

Here's the code:

```
....

fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeatures)

#---------------------------------------------
# Add fields to a feature class:
#---------------------------------------------
fieldList = ["field1", "field2", "field3", ............., "field99"]  #<-- fieldList
fieldListx = []
for f in fieldList:
    fieldx = f+"x"
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldx, "DOUBLE")
    fieldListx.append(fieldx)

#---------------------------------------------
# Calculate fields:
#---------------------------------------------
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
    for fieldx in fieldListx:
        field = fieldx.rstrip('x')
        value = row.getValue(field)* row.anotherField  #<--This is the line the error is referring to
        row.setValue(fieldx,value)
    rows.updateRow(row)
del row, rows
```

Is this an issue of memory or something? Why does it produce an error before Calculate Fields when I add the full list of 108 fields, but not when I run a small sample of only 3? Thanks!!

Comment: G, Is your code erroring at the same field calculation each time (for the row.anotherfield?  Is row.anotherfield type non text?

Comment: Yeah, it errors during the 1st iteration, every time.

Comment: Non-text. Hmm... Yea it's a double. But the weird thing is the whole code works fine on a sample set of three fields, but not on the full set of 108 fields.

Comment: Did you try a number of fields between 3 and 108? Might be useful to know at what number of fields it first breaks down. At a minimum, print out the field number on each iteration so we know what field number if chokes on.

Comment: OK, that's a good idea. I'll give it a try. Maybe breaking the list into smaller parts may work...

Comment: Got the error on 50... going to try lower

Comment: So 10 is the limit. 10 worked, 11 did not...

Comment: So that begs the question, what's up with that 11th field? Look into that.

Comment: OK, I've since been trying all sorts of stuff. I switched out the 10th field for the 11th field knowing it was working on 10 fields, thinking maybe something was wrong with #11, and indeed even with 10 fields it still failed. But then I put everything into a geodatabase and ran the same list of goofy fields and it worked. So that 11th field may have been choking it in the shapefile, but not in the geodatabase. But now when I try to run all 108 fields using a geodatabase, I'm still getting the error at the first run through the loop :/

Comment: Try "print"ing the "fieldx" column name.  Because your are experiencing the issue only with a shapefile (limit of 10 characters for the field name), maybe you are running into the classic "fieldname_1", "fieldname_2" issue when adding the new field that has duplicate first 8-10 characters.

Comment: @RyanDalton - I averted that problem by using `env.qualifiedFieldNames = False`. [Check it out](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000008000000). But that *had* been a problem for me earlier, so good call!

Comment: Are you sure the field you are failing on does not have an  **8 character** field name that is a duplicate of one of your previous fields?  As stated in the help you linked to: _"Shapefile fields are truncated at eight characters."_

Comment: @RyanDalton You know what I discovered? Somewhere along the line a character at the end of field #11 _was_ missing. I don't think it was truncated, because other fields weren't (I had made sure previously they were the correct length). But yea, I think it was trying to look for a field in my fieldList that didn't exist because the names didn't match up. So now I know to be way more careful about field names.

Comment: Please add your findings as an "answer" and mark it as accepted so this question is closed.  Thanks, and good for finding the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there are two solutions to the above. I will paste them both below... Thanks everyone for all of your help!

Ultimately the problem WAS with a field name. My field#11 had at some point lost its last letter. When it was being appended to `fieldList` and later asked to "strip" itself of the "x" that had been added to it, it was looking for a field in the feature class that didn't exist. Despite the fact that locating that problem was like finding a needle in a haystack, I fixed it, and I didn't receive the error again. Lesson learned: always check your field names!!

Below, however, are "solutions" simply to writing better code to do what I was trying to do above:

**Solution #1:** 
This one is the best. It requires fewer lines and runs faster. It is the result of a suggestion from @ccn in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56979/am-i-over-complicating-adding-and-then-calculating-fields-suggestions-for-a-bet). I tweaked it just slightly by including quotations around the static field name `UNpctOfEd`.

```
....

fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeatures)

fieldList = ["field1", "field2", "field3", ............., "field105"]  #<-- this has to be done manually for various reasons so I can't just use ListFields

# Loop through fieldList (Add and Calculate fields)
for field in fieldList:
    # local variables
    fieldx = field + "x"
    expression = "!" + field + "! * !" + "UNpctOfEd" + "!" #<-- Jackpot!! Figuring out how to write the expression
    # add/calculate new field
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldx, "DOUBLE")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, fieldx, expression, "PYTHON_9.3")
```

**Solution #2:** 
This one is a working/much better version of what I had in the question above, using `UpdateCursor` although it requires more lines, is more complicated, and is slower than Solution #1:

```
....

fc = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(layerName, outFeatures)

fieldList = ["field1", "field2", "field3", ............., "field105"]  #<-- again, this has to be done manually for various reasons so I can't just use ListFields

# Creating new fields in the feature class
fieldListx = []
for f in fieldList:
    fieldx = f+"x"
    arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldx, "DOUBLE")
    fieldListx.append(fieldx)
print fieldListx

# Calculating those new fields in the feature class
for fieldx in fieldListx:
    rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(fc)
    field = fieldx.rstrip('x')
    for row in rows:
        value = row.getValue(field)* row.UNpctOfEd 
        row.setValue(fieldx,value)
        rows.updateRow(row)
    del row, rows
```